# <console>:22: error: not found: value sc

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I am completely new to Spark, Learning is in progress on Spark. While in practice, facing few issues as below. Multiple steps and quiet long.
 I am using spark-shell in UNIX environment. Getting errors as below.

Step 1

```
    $ spark-shell
    Welcome to
          ____              __
         / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
        _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
       /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.3.1
          /_/

    Using Scala version 2.10.4 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_25)
    Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
    Type :help for more information.
    2016-04-22 07:44:31,5095 ERROR JniCommon fs/client/fileclient/cc/jni_MapRClient.cc:1473 Thread: 20535 mkdirs failed for /user/cni/.sparkStaging/application_1459074732364_1192326, error 13
    org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException: User cni(user id 5689)  has been denied access to create application_1459074732364_1192326
            at com.mapr.fs.MapRFileSystem.makeDir(MapRFileSystem.java:1100)
            at com.mapr.fs.MapRFileSystem.mkdirs(MapRFileSystem.java:1120)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.mkdirs(FileSystem.java:1851)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.mkdirs(FileSystem.java:631)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.prepareLocalResources(Client.scala:224)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.createContainerLaunchContext(Client.scala:384)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.submitApplication(Client.scala:102)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.start(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:58)
            at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:141)
            at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.(SparkContext.scala:381)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.createSparkContext(SparkILoop.scala:1016)
            at $iwC$$iwC.(:9)
            at $iwC.(:18)
            at (:20)
            at .(:24)
            at .()
            at .(:7)
            at .()
            at $print()
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1338)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:856)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:901)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:813)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoopInit.scala:123)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoopInit.scala:122)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.beQuietDuring(SparkIMain.scala:324)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.initializeSpark(SparkILoopInit.scala:122)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.initializeSpark(SparkILoop.scala:64)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$5.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:973)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.runThunks(SparkILoopInit.scala:157)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.runThunks(SparkILoop.scala:64)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.postInitialization(SparkILoopInit.scala:106)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.postInitialization(SparkILoop.scala:64)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:990)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:944)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:944)
            at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:944)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1058)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:569)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:166)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:189)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:110)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext.(SQLContext.scala:145)
            at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.(HiveContext.scala:49)
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
            at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.createSQLContext(SparkILoop.scala:1027)
            at $iwC$$iwC.(:9)
            at $iwC.(:18)
            at (:20)
            at .(:24)
            at .()
            at .(:7)
            at .()
            at $print()
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1338)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:856)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:901)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:813)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoopInit.scala:130)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$$anonfun$initializeSpark$1.apply(SparkILoopInit.scala:122)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.beQuietDuring(SparkIMain.scala:324)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.initializeSpark(SparkILoopInit.scala:122)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.initializeSpark(SparkILoop.scala:64)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1$$anonfun$apply$mcZ$sp$5.apply$mcV$sp(SparkILoop.scala:973)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.runThunks(SparkILoopInit.scala:157)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.runThunks(SparkILoop.scala:64)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoopInit$class.postInitialization(SparkILoopInit.scala:106)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.postInitialization(SparkILoop.scala:64)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:990)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:944)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:944)
            at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:944)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1058)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
            at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:569)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:166)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:189)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:110)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

    :10: error: not found: value sqlContext
           import sqlContext.implicits._
                  ^
    :10: error: not found: value sqlContext
           import sqlContext.sql
                  ^
```

Step 2:

I just ignored warning/errors above, and moved on with my code. I read that, sc will get created automatically if i use spark-shell, So coded as below.

```
<pre>
scala> val textFile = sc.textFile("README.md")
<console>:13: error: not found: value sc
       val textFile = sc.textFile("README.md")
</pre>
```

Step 3: 
As it is saying sc not found, tried creating it.

```
scala> import org.apache.spark._
import org.apache.spark._

scala> import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.streaming._

scala> import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext._

scala> val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").setAppName("NetworkWordCount").set("spark.ui.port", "44040" ).set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")
conf: org.apache.spark.SparkConf = org.apache.spark.SparkConf@1a58697d

scala> val ssc = new StreamingContext(conf, Seconds(2) )
16/04/22 08:19:18 WARN SparkContext: Another SparkContext is being constructed (or threw an exception in its constructor).  This may indicate an error, since only one SparkContext may be running in this JVM (see SPARK-2243). The other SparkContext was created at:
org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:80)
org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.createSparkContext(SparkILoop.scala:1016)
$line3.$read$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:9)
$line3.$read$$iwC.<init>(<console>:18)
$line3.$read.<init>(<console>:20)
$line3.$read$.<init>(<console>:24)
$line3.$read$.<clinit>(<console>)
$line3.$eval$.<init>(<console>:7)
$line3.$eval$.<clinit>(<console>)
$line3.$eval.$print(<console>)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1338)
org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:856)
ssc: org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext = org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext@15492914
```

As spark told me it is warning(of course also said, it may indicate error), So ignored and moved on to create RDD. Again, Here I am not sure, Is this an error/Warning???

step 4

Created RDD as follows.

```
<pre>

scala> var fil = ssc.textFile("/mapr/datalake/01.Call_ID.txt")
<console>:21: error: value textFile is not a member of org.apache.spark.streaming.StreamingContext
       var fil = ssc.textFile("/mapr/datalake/01.Call_ID.txt")
                     ^

</pre>
```

Here it is saying me textFile is not a member of streamingContext. I am going mad with all these. Also, I am working for a company, executing scripts in company's laptop(JFYI).

Answer (score 0):

I think all of this is due to a lack of permissions. Presuming you have the correct access priveleges to use the cluster you can type

`HADOOP_USER_NAME=hdfs spark-shell`

That should overwrite the permissions of your account.

Comment: Tried HADOOP_USER_NAME=hdfs spark-shell and HADOOP_USER_NAME=cni spark-shell
But it is giving me same errors.(cni is my user name)
How to check for permissions, that i have ???

Comment: It might be that there are no permissions set. Try running hadoop fs -ls / that should at least see if you have any file access permissions.

Comment: $ hadoop fs -ls /
Found 9 items
drwxr-xr-x   - mapr mapr          1 2016-04-05 16:29 /apps
drwxrwxrwx   - mapr mapr          1 2014-09-29 15:45 /benchmarks
drwxr-xr-x   - mapr mapr         16 2016-02-02 00:03 /datalake
drwxr-xr-x   - mapr mapr          0 2013-12-10 16:35 /hbase
drwxr-xr-x   - mapr mapr          0 2014-09-27 08:14 /tables
drwxrwxrwx   - mapr mapr       1124 2016-04-22 22:40 /tmp
drwxr-xr-x   - mapr mapr         18 2016-04-14 14:06 /user
drwxr-xr-x   - mapr mapr          1 2013-12-10 16:35 /var
drwxrwxrwt   - mapr mapr        356 2016-04-22 11:43 /yarnlogs

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are having issues to create a folder inside your user directory in HDFS.

Check the permissions on folder: **/user/cni/**

You can try giving all access to your user folder with the command:

```
hdfs dfs -chmod -R 777 /user/cni
```

This is not recommended in shared clusters or in production but it could help you to identify if it is an access issue.